# Watched Tables / Email Queue - What's going on?

Tags: sql-server, email, queue, windows-server-2003

I'm taking over a project and am having trouble tracking down a particular mechanism. I have a database with several tables and triggers. One of those tables is called `MailQueue`. I have a ticket tracking web app that uses this database, and certain actions in the app cause a message to be generated and inserted into the `MailQueue` table. Periodically (Every 5-10 minutes? Hard to tell) the messages get sent and the table emptied. Also, every morning at 6am reminders get sent out regarding unfinished tickets which were previously submitted via the web app.

I've been searching for days trying to find where and how these messages are sent out, both from the queue periodically and every morning at 6am. I've checked triggers, SQL Server jobs, Scheduled Tasks, and everywhere in the codebehind and I'm coming up dry.

Based on the characteristics I described, does anyone have any bright ideas how this might be happening? Here are the app and environment vitals.

- Windows Server 2003
- IIS 6 (.NET 1.1 App Pool)
- SQL Server 2005

Thanks :)

Comment: The easiest place to start would be to use SQL Profiler to trace whatever is happening with the `MailQueue` table, that should help you narrow things down quite quickly.

Comment: @Pondlife: I'm not sure yet if this will get me what I'm looking for but it's a great start and a good answer. If you re-post as an answer I'll give it to you. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest place to start would be to use SQL Profiler to trace whatever is happening with the `MailQueue` table, that should help you narrow things down quite quickly.